# jQuery - mousemove on dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger mousemove insinde a dynamic created element called '.box'. How can I add this condition to the following code?

jQuery

```
                $(document).mousemove(function (event) {
                  .....
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $(document).on('mousemove', '.box', function (event) {

 });
```

This is a *delegated event handler* and works by listening for the event to bubble up to a non-changing ancestor. It *then* applies the jQuery selector *at event time* to the elements in the bubble chain. It *then* applies the function to any matching elements *that caused the event*.

The upshot of this is that the elements only need to exist when the event happens, not when the event is registered.

`document` is the default if nothing is closer. Do not use `'body'` as the default as it will not always respond to mouse events (styling can cause it to have a zero computed height).

Answer (score 1):

Try this : use `.on()` to bind event to the dynamically created elements. This actually delegate the event to the matched element inside `document`

```
$(document).on("mousemove", ".box", function (event) {
                  .....
});
```

Comment: Actually "delegate" means the opposite. The event is *delegated* to an *ancestor* to handle. Delegate: "a person designated to act for or represent another or others". `document` is the delegate.